# Javascript — escape a character entity (→ is showing as &rarr;)

Tags: javascript, string, dom

```
document.title = ("hello &rarr; goodbye");
```

This is not outputting the arrow: "→" as it should.
How does one escape that so it does?

Comment: That's _Javascript_, not jQuery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to escape it at all.

Just write

```
document.title = "hello → goodbye";
```

(and make sure your file is UTF8)

If you really want to escape it, you can use a Javsacript escape code: `"\u2192"`

Entities are only used in HTML source; you cannot use them in ordinary strings.  (Except for `innerHTML`, which is HTML source)

Comment: Awesome that worked. It's a newbie question, but i reckon it will be put to good use for other newbies hitting a blank with this. Sometimes the answer is much simpler then you think... actually, a lot of the time.

Comment: Is it safe to NOT escape whatever you are assigning to `document.title`, if that data is untrusted?

Comment: @buffer: Yes.  `document.title` is a plain string.  The whole point of escaping is to insert arbitrary text into a structured language.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the [JavaScript character escape sequence](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) `\u2192`:

```
document.title = "hello \u2192 goodbye";
```

Or, as [SLaks points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538876/jquery-escape-a-character-entity-is-showing-as-rarr/5538924#5538924), if the JavaScript file is in Unicode, you can put it directly in the code:

```
document.title = ("hello → goodbye");
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the HTML `<title>` tag permits mark-up at all, it just treats everything as a string literal. In other words, don't try to use HTML entities in your script, just use the actual "→" character.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not true.  However, JS strings do not support support entities.

Comment: @SLaks Yep, quite right, titles do allow for entities, my bad: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-TITLE